# canvas.toDataURL('image/svg+xml') returning "data:image/png;base64..."

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to export the canvas into svg . but the toDataURL function returning the data as  "data:image/png;base64..."

*I don't want to use complex function/library .*

I am using the below  if any one can modify it also ,it is helpful for me

```
             var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL('image/svg+xml');
             if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1 && 
             navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") === -1) {
                console.log(dataURL);
                window.open(dataURL);
              } else {
                 var parts = dataURL.split(';base64,');
                  var contentType = parts[0].split(":")[1];
                  var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
                  var rawLength = raw.length;
                  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
                    console.log(uInt8Array);

                  for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
                    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
                  }

                var blob = new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.style = "display: none";
                a.href = url;
                a.download = orientation +".svg";

                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();

                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

The <canvas> element only holds a pixels buffer.
Even though the 2D API is mostly based on vector drawings, the actual content is only raster.

Exporting to svg is not an option in any mainstream browser.

This means that your `'image/svg+xml'` will not be recognized anywhere and indeed they will fallback to `image/png`.

You said you don't want to use complex function/library, so let's just say you're out of luck, because the solutions implies to overwrite all the drawing operations in order to build pathes that can be mapped to SVG elements, which is not straightforward, (even if all is mostly doable, except ImageData pixel manips).
If you really want to do this, then you may want to have a look at some libraries, [this one](https://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/) seems to be made only for this purpose, so I hope it's lightweight an performant enough, though I **never** used it myself, [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) has such an option too, but then we're clearly in the heavy-weighted category.

Comment: I have used the fabric js where the tosvg function is not working for my case. you can see this issue also.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242972/svg-export-is-not-working-properly-by-modifying-the-text-rendering-function-in-f

Comment: You did well asking that question there, a lot of users (among which Durga) are quite knowledgeable about fabric.js (a lot more than myself) so be patient, you'll get an appropriate answer. For the one at hand, I'm sorry the answer is deceptive, but that's the only one I can make.